# Get field value if field does exists or default value if not, DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a following question:

for example I have 3 almost similar models:

```
Model_A(models.Model)
field_1 = ….
field_2 = ….
field_3 = ….

Model_B(models.Model)
field_1 = ….
field_2 = ….
field_3 = ….


Model_C(models.Model)
field_1 = ….
field_2 = ….
# no field 3 here
```

And I want to make a method in serializers.py where I would do something like that:

```
def funk(self, model)
# model is Model_A, B or C

    model.objects.annotate(
    result= Coalesce( F(“field_3), Value(value=1,output_field=IntegerField())
    ).etc_etc_etc…

    return something here
```

Goal is like this:
if field_3 in model does exist, I want to get it’s value, if not, I want to get default value from `Value()`.

Problem is that if `field_3` in model doesn't exists it would through exception instead of just providing `NULL` value, which is logically correct...

Is it any way to implement such logic on a DB level by DB or ORM instruments?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Coalesce` does not deal with a missing *column*, it deals with a value that is not there.

You can however simply inspect the model by accessing the `_meta` options, and see if there is such column, for example with [**`.get_field(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field):

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField

def funk(self, model):
    try:
        model._meta.get_field('field_3')
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        return model.objects.annotate(
            field_3=Value(1, output_field=IntegerField())
        )
    else:
        return model.objects.all()
```

You can "parameterize" the column name, and run it for example several times to inject values for all missing columns in the `model`.